# caret::predict giving Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, r-caret, naivebayes

This has been driving me crazy and I've been looking through similar posts all day but can't seem to solve my problem. I have a naive bayes model trained and stored as `model`. I'm attempting to predict with a `newdata` data frame but I keep getting the error  `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. Here is what I am running: `stats::predict(model, newdata = newdata)` where `newdata` is the first row of another data frame: `new data <- pbp[1, c("balls", "strikes", "outs_when_up", "stand", "pitcher", "p_throws", "inning")]`

`class(newdata)` gives `[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I know sorry, I was trying to think how I could give you the model but I'm not sure how. I could give you the training code but it takes like 6 hours to train. Would giving you an actual row of values for `newdata` help?

Comment: Maybe I can try giving you a link to the .Rdata files? Try this Google link, the model is too big for Github. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HppF0msWias4sqxYmlTXO6EAz1bJKCZy?usp=sharing

Comment: That's not really that helpful. Maybe create a simple example using a build in data set that shows the code you used to fit the model and make the prediction. See if you can get the same error message. It's not even clear what type of object `model` is at the moment.

Comment: This is essentially how I fit the data but I'm struggling to reproduce the same error. `model <- caret::train(iris[, 1:4], iris$Species, method = "nb", preProc = c("center", "scale"))`
`newdata <- as_tibble(newdata)`
`stats::predict(model, newdata = newdata[1, c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")])`
I added the line to force the tibble because when I query the newdata that I use, it comes back as a tibble already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the data used.  it should match the `levels` used in the training.  E.g. if we use one of the rows from trainingData to `predict`, it does work

```
predict(model, head(model$trainingData, 1))
#[1] Curveball
#Levels: Changeup Curveball Fastball Sinker Slider
```

---

By checking the `str` of both datasets, some of the `factor` columns in the training is `character` class

```
str(model$trainingData)
'data.frame':   1277525 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ pitcher     : Factor w/ 1390 levels "112526","115629",..: 277 277 277 277 277 277 277 277 277 277 ...
 $ stand       : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ p_throws    : Factor w/ 2 levels "L","R": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ balls       : num  0 1 0 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 ...
 $ strikes     : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 2 ...
 $ outs_when_up: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ .outcome    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Changeup","Curveball",..: 3 4 1 4 1 5 5 1 1 5 ...

str(newdata)
tibble [1 × 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ balls       : int 3
 $ strikes     : int 2
 $ outs_when_up: int 1
 $ stand       : chr "R"
 $ pitcher     : int 605200
 $ p_throws    : chr "R"
```

---

An option is to make `levels` same for `factor` class

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(model$trainingData), names(newdata))
nm2 <- names(which(sapply(model$trainingData[nm1], is.factor)))
newdata[nm2] <- Map(function(x, y) factor(x, levels = levels(y)), newdata[nm2], model$trainingData[nm2])
```

Now do the `predict`ion

```
predict(model, newdata)
#[1] Sinker
#Levels: Changeup Curveball Fastball Sinker Slider
```

Comment: That seems to still be giving me the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Ah weird, I'll look into the levels thank you.

Comment: Brilliant! You nailed it, apparently the ID for pitcher that gets pulled for the newdata defaults to an int when there is only one row. Thank you so much!